1000 balls and 100 boxes
There are $1000$ balls labelled $000,001,...,999$ and $100$ boxes labelled $00,01,...,99$. A ball is allowed to put in a box if the number of the box could be obtained by removing one digit from the number of the ball. For example, ball 134 could be put into box $13$, $14$ or $34$. Show that we need at least $50$ boxes for all balls to fit in.

I have constructed a way to put $1000$ balls into $50$ boxes: Choose the boxes with number $xy$ where $|x-y|$ equals $0,2$ or $4 \pmod{10}$. That is,
00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99
02, 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 79, 80, 91
04, 15, 26, ...                   , 93
06, 17, 28, ...                   , 95
08, 19, 20, ...                   , 97

Now I struggle on proving $49$ boxes is not enough. I attempt to find some balls that need to go into different boxes such as $123,147,789$ but it is nowhere near $50$. Seems like it requires some case work but I don't see a delicate way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Just to clarify, if we number a box $0$ does this mean the balls labelled 0001,..., 0009, 0010,...0020...,0100 can all be put into this box? If so, I can see the beginning of a strategy.

Sorry I don't quite understand your question.
For ball number 001, it can go into box number 00 or 01.

Maybe this could be solved by using Hall's Marriage Theorem, which see.

You might try induction on the base of the number system. For binary it is easy to see you need 2 boxes, for base 3 you need 5 boxes. I haven't got much further yet.

This is a covering problem. The box xy covers the balls zxy, xzy and xyz for all z. As mentioned in the comments, it is natural to consider the base of the number system as variable.
This question is solved in the paper A Combinatorial Problem in Matching by J. G. Kalbfleisch, R. G. Stanton. The answer is that at least $\left\lceil \frac{p^2}{2} \right\rceil$ boxes are needed when the base is $p$. They consider covering vectors of same length and covering means that vectors agree in at least $2$ (or more generally $n-1$) components, so I guess it amounts to the same thing as adding one more component (of any value, to any place).
I'll try and modify the proof here for this case.
Let's prove $49$ boxes aren't enough. Assume to the contrary: There are boxes $H_j = (a_j, b_j)$ for $j=1,\dots, 49$ that cover all the $10^3$ balls. Consider the least frequent component in the vectors $H_j$. Denote the frequency by $m$. Clearly $m \leq 4$. By permuting the problem we may assume it is an $a_j$ component and rearranging the $H_j$'s we may also assume the repetitions appear in the beginning, i.e.
$$a_1=a_2=\dots = a_m=a$$
and
$$a_j \neq a, \text{ for } j>m.$$
So now we want to choose $b \neq b_j$ for $j>m$ and $c \in \{0,\dots,9\}$ such that $(a,b,c)$ is not covered by any of the boxes.
Count how many distinct $b_j$-components are among $B_1 := \{b_1,\dots, b_m\}$. Denote it by $r$. Since all these $b_j$'s have frequence at least $m$, there are at least $mr$ occurrences such that $b_j \in B_1$ and at least $mr-m$ of these are such that $j>m$. So when $a \neq a_j$ and $b \neq b_j$ we have that $(a,b,c)$ is not covered by $H_j$ for these $mr-r$ values of $j$. So it must be covered by the remaining $49-m-(rm-m) = 49-rm$ boxes. But $b$ may be chosen in $10-r$ ways and $c$ in at least $10-m$ ways so we must have
$$
(10-r)(10-m) \leq 49-rm
$$
which gives $2(5-r)(5-m) \leq -1$, a contradiction.
PS. Since $a \neq a_j$ and $b \neq b_j$, the covering must happen by adding $c$ to the end. Or I don't know, well I'll post this anyhow...
